# How to list all roles created in mysql 8?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, Roles can be created by the `CREATE ROLE...` statement.

Is there a way to list all the roles created already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The role is saved in the same way as the user. But the role have no password, and its host is always `'%'`. So use

```sql
SELECT user AS role_name
FROM mysql.user
WHERE host = '%'
  AND NOT LENGTH(authentication_string);
```

Comment: @[Akina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10138734/akina) There comes a little problem. What if a user is created by `CREATE USER 'temp'@'%';`.  The temp user is not a role but will be in the roles query result. Anyway I get the great answer I expected, thanks!

Comment: @Runryan MySQL really does not distinguish between roles and users! This user can be easily used instead of a role in GRANT. `DROP ROLE temp;` will delete this user. Accordingly the role can be dropped with `DROP USER` command. And I do not see the way how to distinguish does the account row was created as a role or as a user...